# Looking for a "vectorized" version to store difference of vector elements in matrix

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I am doing the following operation

```
a <- c(3, 7, 1)

M <- matrix(data = NA,
             nrow = 3,
             ncol = 3)
M
# a_i - a_j 
for(i in seq_along(a)) {
  
  for (j in seq_along(a)) {
    
    M[i, j] <- a[i] - a[j]
    
  }
}
```

and wonder if there is a more elegant, i.e. R-like way of doing this. In analogy to `tcrossprod()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `outer` in `base R`

```
outer(a, a, `-`)
```

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(a, `-`, a)
```

Comment: Ah, `outer()` does the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to play with `tcrossprod()`, below might be a trick

```
> tcrossprod(a^0, a) - a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    4   -2
[2,]   -4    0   -6
[3,]    2    6    0
```

but nothing can be more efficient or elegant than `outer`, I think.